# fusion tables importrows

Tags: python, google-fusion-tables

Have anyone used the function importRows() from fusion table API?
As the API reference below, 
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows
I have to supply CSV data in the request body.
But what should I do for the html body exactly?

My code:

```
http = getAuthorizedHttp()

DISCOVERYURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest'

ftable = build('fusiontables', 'v1', discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERYURL, http=http)

body = create_ft(CSVFILE,"title here")   # the function to load csv file and create the table with columns from csv file.
result = ftable.table().insert(body=body).execute()
print result["tableId"]   # good, I have got the id for new created table

# I have no idea how to go on here..
f = ftable.table().importRows(tableId=result["tableId"])
f.body = ?????????????
f.execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem, my code can be found in the following link.
https://github.com/childnotfound/parser/blob/master/uploader.py

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem like this:

```
media = http.MediaFileUpload('example.csv',  mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
request = service.table().importRows(media_body=media, tableId='1cowubQ0vj_H9q3owo1vLM_gMyavvbuoNmRQaYiZV').execute()
```